# Create ecj.jar file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ecj

I made some changes to `elipse.jdt.core` plugin in order to support a language (MaxJ) similar to Java. Changes that I made can be found here:

https://github.com/maxeler/eclipse.jdt.core/tree/MAXJ_4_4_maintenance

Release of my plugin can be found here:

https://github.com/maxeler/eclipse/releases

Everything works fine when I use eclipse in GUI mode but I want to compile different projects from command line (in headless build or using ant) and for that I need to create new `ecj.jar` file. I tried building this library:

https://github.com/maxeler/maxpower

According to this article:

http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-ant_javac_adapter.htm

`jdtCompilerAdapter.jar` can be used instead of `ecj.jar` but that didn't work because it doesn't contain compiler classes (like `CompilerOptions` etc.).
In `build.xml` file I changed the following lines:

```
<taskdef name="maxjcompiler" classname="org.eclipse.jdt.core.ant.taskdef.MaxjTask" classpath="${env.MAXCOMPILERDIR}/lib/MaxIDE/ecj.jar" onerror="ignore"/>
<taskdef name="maxjdoc" classname="org.eclipse.jdt.core.ant.taskdef.MaxjDocTask" classpath="${env.MAXCOMPILERDIR}/lib/MaxIDE/ecj.jar"/>
```

with this:

```
<taskdef name="maxjcompiler" classname="org.eclipse.jdt.core.ant.taskdef.MaxjTask" classpath="/pathToMyJar/jdtCompilerAdapter.jar" onerror="ignore"/>
<taskdef name="maxjdoc" classname="org.eclipse.jdt.core.ant.taskdef.MaxjDocTask" classpath="/home/ikulezic/Desktop/jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
```

And then I run this command to start build process:

```
ant
```

It produces the following error:

```
Buildfile: /home/ikulezic/Desktop/maxpower/build.xml
 [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

clean:
  [delete] Deleting directory /home/ikulezic/Desktop/maxpower/bin

compile:
    [echo] 
    [echo] Using maxeda classpath '/opt/maxcompiler/lib/MaxCompiler.jar'
    [echo]   (Precedence: 1. $MAXCOMPILERJCP, 2. $MAXCOMPILERDIR)
    [echo] 
    [echo]                 
   [mkdir] Created dir: /home/ikulezic/Desktop/maxpower/bin

BUILD FAILED
/home/ikulezic/Desktop/maxpower/build.xml:66: Could not create type maxjcompiler due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/impl/CompilerOptions
       at org.eclipse.jdt.core.ant.taskdef.MaxjTask.<init>(MaxjTask.java:80)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntTypeDefinition.innerCreateAndSet(AntTypeDefinition.java:328)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntTypeDefinition.createAndSet(AntTypeDefinition.java:274)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntTypeDefinition.icreate(AntTypeDefinition.java:219)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntTypeDefinition.create(AntTypeDefinition.java:206)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:285)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:263)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:429)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
       at org.apache.
 at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.impl.CompilerOptions
       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1315)
       at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1068)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
       ... 24 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

At the moment it seems like the only option is to build a new `ecj.jar` file but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Why would you make a screenshot of a console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to build `ecj.jar` depends on what build technology you use.

If you have the context configured so that you can build `org.eclipse.jdt.core` with **Maven/Tycho**, then you should adjust the `batch-compiler` execution within the project's pom.xml.

Otherwise, a more light-weight approach should be to invoke **Ant** with `scripts/export-ecj.xml`. That file may be a bit out-of-date, but you could take a look at how this is adapted for creating another variant of ecj (for [OT/J](http://www.eclipse.org/objectteams)), see: http://git.eclipse.org/c/objectteams/org.eclipse.objectteams.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/scripts/export-ecj.xml.

For OT/J this script is invoked from the Ant-based PDE-build process, so for standalone invocation a bunch of properites needs to be configured first.

- integrating apt and tool requires those sibling projects to sit in expected locations, and properties like `build.root.dir` set. Otherwise, commenting the section for apt and tool should get you going.
- set `buildLabel` to something useful

With these preparations I can successfully run Ant from within the IDE.